# Assistance flattening an array of objects that has an object (or potential more than 1) within

Tags: javascript, json, object

I am trying to flatten an array of objects that has an object within that object (but also could have more). The resulting format should just an array of objects.

Here is how it is currently:

```
var array = [
  {
    nickname: "Johnny",
    first_name: "John",
    last_name: "Smith",
    info: {
      married: "yes",
      kids_ages: []
    }
  },
  {
    {
    nickname: "Ron",
    first_name: "Ronald",
    last_name: "Smith",
    info: {
      married: "no",
      kids_ages: []
    }
  },
  {
    nickname: "Johnny",
    first_name: "John",
    last_name: "Smith",
    info: {
      married: "yes",
      kids_ages: [17]
    },
    kids: {
      first_name: "Harry",
      last_name: "Smith
  }
 }
]
```

Should be like this for the first entry:

```
{
  nickname: "Johnny",
  first_name: "John",
  last_name: "Smith",
  married: "yes"
  kids_ages: []
},
```

Comment: Try `array.prototype.map` and then on each object  `array.prototype.reduce`. Think of conflicts. What to do in the last object, when you have `first_name` in `kids` object and in parent object. You want to keep both, the last one, the first one, some random one? :)

Comment: what about same property names?

Answer (score 1):

You could get `info` out of the object and assign this object with the rest to a single object.

```js
var array = [{ nickname: "Johnny", first_name: "John", last_name: "Smith", info: { married: "yes", kids_ages: [] } }, { nickname: "Ron", first_name: "Ronald", last_name: "Smith", info: { married: "no", kids_ages: [] } }, { nickname: "Johnny", first_name: "John", last_name: "Smith", info: { married: "yes", kids_ages: [17] }, kids: { first_name: "Harry", last_name: "Smith" } }],
    flat = array.map(({ info, ...object }) => ({ ...object, ...info }));

console.log(flat);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A different approach by keeping the key of the outer object as prefix.

```js
function getFlat(object, parent) {
    return Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(object).map(([k, v]) => {
        if (v && typeof v === 'object' && !Array.isArray(v)) {
            return getFlat(v, k);
        }
        return { [parent  + (parent && '_') + k]: v };
    }));
}

var array = [{ nickname: "Johnny", first_name: "John", last_name: "Smith", info: { married: "yes", kids_ages: [] } }, { nickname: "Ron", first_name: "Ronald", last_name: "Smith", info: { married: "no", kids_ages: [] } }, { nickname: "Johnny", first_name: "John", last_name: "Smith", info: { married: "yes", kids_ages: [17] }, kids: { first_name: "Harry", last_name: "Smith" } }],
    flat = array.map(o => getFlat(o));

console.log(flat);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

From my comment: 
Try `array.prototype.map` and then on each object `array.prototype.reduce`. Think of conflicts. What to do in the last object, when you have `first_name` in kids object and in parent object. You want to keep both, the last one, the first one, some random one?

For instance:

```
const flat = arr => arr.map(element => 
  Object.entries(element).reduce((sum, [key, value]) => { 
    if (isObject(value)) {
      return {...sum, ...value}
      // or anything else to manage conflicts, depends on the way you want to handle it
    } 
  return {...sum, [key]: value }
}, {}))
```